# Select and validate multiple TextFields in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, validation, uitextfield, xamarin

I've got multiple TextFields that are generated from a Json file into a TableViewController. The TextFields all have `99` as Tag. I've got a RightBarButton and when that button is pressed the Console should show the values in the TextFields but only the value of the last TextField is shown.

How can I validate them all so I can check if all the TextFields have data in them?

This is my RightBarButton:

```
NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem (
    new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save, ((sender, e) => {
        ValidateEditFields();
    }))
, true);
```

And this is ValidateEditFields():

```
public virtual void ValidateEditFields(){
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", TextField.Text);
}
```

This is how I add the TextFields to the TableCells:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        if (elements [indexPath.Row].Type == "textField") {

            EditField element = elements [indexPath.Row] as EditField;

            NSString FieldID = new NSString ("EditField");

            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (FieldID);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            var setTextField = cell.ViewWithTag (99) as UITextField;

            if (setTextField == null) {
                TextField = new UITextField ();
                TextField.Placeholder = element.Placeholder;
                TextField.Tag = 99;
                TextField.SecureTextEntry = element.Secure;

                cell.AddSubview (TextField);

                EditFieldProperties ();
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = element.Label;
            cell.DetailTextLabel.Hidden = true;

            return cell;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Get you add the code that do adding textfields to the cell?

Comment: This won't work, for a couple of reasons.  First, TextField will only ever point to the last UITextField you created.  Second, due to how iOS handles TableViews, cells will be reused.  This is really an ideal scenario for MonoTouch.Dialog.

Comment: But can I make custom TableCells in MonoTouch.Dialog? I've read the docs but I only saw the standard elements in there.

Comment: At all what I can suggest that will not require rewrite a lot of code, it's to hold all textfields in some array, and you will be able to easily access to them in any time, but it's not the best solution

Comment: But how can I put all the TextFields in an array? I don't know how to loop them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a new List of UITextFields like this:

```
public List<UITextField> TextFieldList = new List<UITextField>();
```

Add them to the list in the `GetCell` method like this:

```
if (setTextField == null) {
    TextField = new UITextField ();

    TextFieldList.Add(TextField);        

    cell.AddSubview (TextField);
}
```

And looping them like this inside my `ValidateEditFields`:

```
foreach (UITextField item in TextFieldList) {
    if (item.Text == "") {
        item.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    } else {
         Console.WriteLine (item.Text);
    }
}
```